# Help with validation errors coming from Flash param

Tags: html, validation, embed

We embed some flash stuff onto our site (YouTube videos + an audio player), and they're causing most of our validation errors.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.greendayauthority.com/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Getting a lot of these

> Element param not allowed as child of element object in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Can someone help explain the proper way of setting this up so it doesn't cause so many errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `param` (and the load of other HTML usually used for embedding Flash into webpages) are not valid HTML, as you can probably see in this case. Instead, you should try to use another method to embed your Flash content, like [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

With this, you can handle cross browser compatibility issues and Flash player version checking using Javascript *and* get valid HTML.